# What is the most concise script to list the missing ones in a digit sequence?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

For example,  we have the content

```
001
002
004
008
010
```

in a text file named `file`, how to extract the missing `3 5 6 7 9`?

Comment: @don_crissti I need digits, not filename

Comment: Nothing stops you to extract the number from the filename. You can adapt any of the answers there to do that.

Comment: @don_crissti some strings in the filename are random. I cannot use the same way in the link. I guess regular expression is necessary. Anyhow, I edited the post to make it a new one.

Comment: Sure, after a dozen edits it's no longer a duplicate...

Comment: this should work - `comm -23 <(printf '%03d\n' {1..10}) file`

Comment: @1_CR it's so simple and really works. It's the most wanted answer. can you post it as an answer and it's better to remove the zeros before nontrivial digits, e.g. `2` rather than `002`, `12` rather than `012`

Comment: @don_crissti  so, how about remove the duplication remark?

Comment: It's not a "remark", it's a vote and 4 other people have voted too so I can't "remove" it. You've been here long enough... you should know by now how to properly phrase a question and that changing requirements is strongly discouraged - I mean, look at your post - now it has almost nothing in common with the initial version (and if memory servers me well, this isn't the first time you're changing the requirements; stop doing that).

Comment: Lee, I cannot post an answer to a closed question. For stripping leading zeroes you may pipe to a post-processor, so that makes it something like `comm -23 <(printf '%03d\n' {1..10}) file | awk '{print +$0}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `awk` way:

```
$ awk 'NR != $1 { for (i = prev + 1; i < $1; i++) {print i} } { prev = $1 + 1 }' file
3
5
6
7
9
```

More clearly:

```
awk 'NR != $1 {
  for (i = prev + 1; i < $1; i++) {
    print i
  }
} 
{ 
  prev = $1
}'
```

For each line, I check if the line number matches the number, and if not, prints every number between the previous number (`prev`) and the current number (exclusive, hence `i = prev + 1`).

Comment: I copied the code but the output on my PC is 6 7.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to have control over the size of your numbers for that I would initialize two variable: starting and ending limit and append starting limit to the file name, Loop indefinite, compare start end limit and exit if starting number is greater than ending number, check if file exists and increment start limit.

```
StartNumber=$1
EndNumber=$2

while true; do
      [ ${StartNumber} -gt ${EndNumber} ] && { exit 0 ; }
      if [ ! -f ${FileName}_${StartNumber} ]; then
       echo ${StartNumber}
      fi
      ((StartNumber+=1))
done
```

Couple of suggestions from your comments:

- Try running find command `find . -type f` and loop thru the results.
- For every file the above command produces apply `echo ${filename} | tr -dc 0-9` to get the numbers only.
- You would probably get "yyyyddd" use that as your starting limit and
  compare that with today's date as ending limit.

Comment: thanks, but I cannot specify a `$FileName`. it varies. The filename contains timestamp when saving the file so it could be different.

Comment: Ok, At some point there needs to be something in common or regularity to automate the process otherwise the script gets long and complicated.
Can you tell me the timestamp format?

Comment: 7 digits as `yyyyddd`

Comment: @Lee if your files don't match the example you've given us in your question, how are we supposed to be able to come up with valid suggestions? Please edit your question to provide real examples.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your example file is used, the following command

`join  -a 1 -o 1.1 2.1 -e missed  <(seq -f '%03g' $(tail -1 <(sort file))) file | grep missed`

will produce this output

`003 missed
005 missed
006 missed
007 missed
009 missed`

if that's what you need, i can provide some explanations